# using jQuery to get current URL / path name > and detect if changes

Tags: jquery

I want to use jQuery to detect and get current URL / path, and if it changes from that, detect the change, and then `.hide()` an element with jQuery with typical jQuery `.hide()` method. Basically I want to show a element on a one page application only on the /#/home.php page any page after it will `.hide()`

So, get current URL.

If current URL is no longer as defined above,

`.hide()` div.

---

Or, alternatively: Display div content only if current URL is X.

Comment: which framework are you using angular, backbone or other than these ?

Comment: Yes. But I hate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking to act upon the change of hash or new url? For hash handling:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
 // handle the show/ hide of element here
})
```

Otherwise, you can use location object to find the URL values liek host, href etc.

```
$(location).attr('href');

$(location).attr('pathname');
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no event in jQuery where it detects the url changing or whatsoever. But, I've come across this once and I used `LocalStorage` to solve my issue. Here's how my code mostly looks like.

**E.g.**

*Page 1*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Check if browser supports LocalStorage
    if(typeof(Storage) !== 'undefined') {
        var origin = document.location.origin; // e.g. "http://stackoverflow.com"
        var pathname = document.location.pathname; // e.g. "/questions/36975059/using-jquery-to-get-current-url-path-name-and-detect-if-changes"

        localStorage.setItem('origin', origin);
        localStorage.setItem('pathname', pathname);
    }
});
```

*Page 2 (Or wherever you want to detect if it changes)*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Check if browser supports LocalStorage
    if(typeof(Storage) !== 'undefined') {
        var origin = document.location.origin;
        var pathname = document.location.pathname;

        // Check if it changes here
        var storageOrigin = localStorage.getItem('origin');
        var storagePathname = localStorage.getItem('pathname');

        // Check if storageOrigin and storagePathname are not null or undefined.
        if (storageOrigin && storagePathname) {
            if (storageOrigin !== origin || storagePathname !== pathname) {
                // The previous origin and pathname are not the same. Do your things here.
            }
            else {
                // They're like the same.
            }
        }

        localStorage.setItem('origin', origin);
        localStorage.setItem('pathname', pathname);
    }
});
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `window.location.href` along with `Object.prototype.watch`, although this function  is currently only in Firefox Gecko (as of this answer) and this implementation by [Eli Grey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/78436/eli-grey) should be included: https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583